# TF_agents: Different results with same random seed

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently training a dqn and reinforce agent with the tf_agents library. I do not get the same results despite setting the following random seeds:

```
random.seed(0),
tf.random.set_seed(0),
np.random.seed(0),
tf.compat.v1.set_random_seed(0),
tf.experimental.numpy.random.seed(0)
```

My py environment just uses numpy for random number generation. So I expected this to actually work.
What can I do to get replicable results?

(The issue was already raised on Github (https://github.com/tensorflow/agents/issues/366) but not solved.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems like you just want to generate the same random numbers over and over. If this is the case, you can try to do the following:

```
seed = 0
x = 5
rnd = np.random.RandomState(seed)
z = rnd.randn(x)
```

You can call some other methods from numy.random on the rnd object, like rnd.ranom(x) or rnd.randint(x, y).
If you want to have replicable results with respect to tensorflow initializations, you can specify an initializer for each layer, which then takes a seed as an argument.
For example:

```
initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=4)
```

This should result in weights that are initialized the same every time.